# Alternative to Open DNS

Tags: dns, opendns

do you know of any alternatives to open DNS. I'm sick and tired of having to see the sites that I want to block every time I reboot my system they reappear again. I have the updater and set the the ipv4 to have the IP of Open DNS 208.67.222.222. But still won't work. Do you know of any alternatives.

Comment: Try using your hosts file or a more complicated program like ProtoWall or the Adblock Plus extension for Firefox to block websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it's Google DNS. 
Try these ones :

8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4

Comment: what site will I set this up so that I can block sites?

Comment: just edit your hosts.txt ;p

Comment: I find that googleDNS sometimes doesn't work with some of my local website . So I change my secondary DNS to 208.67.222.222

Answer (score 2):

If you have a router, try changing the DNS settings in it. This way, all the devices in your network benefit from OpenDNS, you don't have to change your IPv4 settings, and it will of course persist through a reboot.

Otherwise, you should separate your question out to the sub-questions; "what is the best solution to block websites" or similar, and "why don't my IPv4 settings persist through a reboot". The other answers are suggesting alternate DNS services like you asked for, when really you need your website blocking problem fixed or your IPv4 settings problem fixed (or both).

P.S. Why did you accept the answer suggesting Google Public DNS, when it isn't able to block websites?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) ?

and also [DNS Advantage](http://www.dnsadvantage.com/index.html) and [ScrubIT](http://www.scrubit.com/) ?